# How to fix build error when running `react-native run-windows`?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, react-native, msbuild

After running `react-native windows` in a freshly initialized React Native app, if you immediately run `react-native run-windows` this error happens:

`Build failed with message Error: Command failed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" 
"C:/<path_to_project>/windows/<project_name>.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndProperty;Verbosity=minimal /nologo
/p:Configuration=debug /p:Platform=x86
. Check your build configuration.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen when you have installed Visual Studio, but never started it as "devenv.exe" before trying to use some commandline tools. There is some additional setup that happens on first launch of Visual Studio before the commandline tools can be invoked by the `react-native run-windows` command.

See the React Native Windows troubleshooting section for more information:
https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/0.60-stable/current/docs/SetupTroubleshooting.md